# Accessing derived attributes in a named tuple from parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance, namedtuple

I have a simple named tuple which functions as a immutable container that characterize a class I designed.

From this Class (that has the namedtuple as class variable), I dervied multiple childclasses that all override this attribute and add new fields to the named tuple

I want to keep the fields that were defined in the Parent class ID and only add the ones that are new. I assume you could simply keep the old ID in the class and do something like ID.2nd = "added form child"
But I'd much prefere if you could simply override the ID variable and acess the previously defined ID's via a call to super() or something

```
from collections import namedtuple

ID = namedtuple("myTuple", ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])
ID.__new__.__defaults__ = ("default from parentclass", None , None , None)


class Parent(object):
    _ID = ID()

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

class Child(Parent):
    #if there is a new _ID defined in Child
    #, keep the fields it adds but also add the
    #ones from the parent:
    _ID = ID(second="adding from child")
    #it should now contain the fields _ID.first == "default from parent" from parentclass
    #and _ID.second == "adding from child"
```

So far this works, but if I have another child now

```
class Child2(Child):

    _ID = ID(third="adding from child")
    #and now something like _ID.second = super()._ID.second
```

I will lose all information that was added in the intermediate classes.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? Why is it tagged as both?

Comment: I am using six so it should preferably be compatible to both versions. If not possible Py 3

Comment: I don't know a solution to your situation, but I had problems running your code until I figured out that `1st` is NOT a valid field name for the namedtuple (the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) say that a field cannot start with a digit, only with letters). Please be careful to add a reproducible example in future questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Updated it, thanks for the headsup

Comment: Also, starting with `Python 3.7` there is a keyword `defaults`, so you could avoid assigning the default values to `ID.__new__.__defaults__ = `. But if you are looking for compatibility with older versions then that would not be an option for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can only work incorporating the same logic that class inheritance has into your NamedTuple attributes - there is no way it could work with stand alone NamedTuple resources: the mechanism have to know, somehow, about your inheritance chain.

A nice place to do that, is to hook something when each subclass is created - for Python versions prior to 3.6, that would imply creating a metaclass. But since, the special class method `__init_subclass__` can do the job.

What has to be done is somewhat straightforward. However, the usual mechanism for fetching things from super-classes, `super()` won't work for class attribute, due to the way it is designed - so we have to reimplement it - I choose to do that in a one liner that will just skip superclasses until one that explicitly defines the `_ID` attribute is found (the code would be barely readable without this context) - and then we have  some extra code to extract the non-default arguments and merge them in a new ID instance.

This is the code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

ID = namedtuple("myTuple", ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])
ID.__new__.__defaults__ = ("default from parentclass", None , None , None)


class A:
    _ID = ID()
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kw):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kw)
        if "_ID" in cls.__dict__:
            _sentinel = object()
            new_fields = [cls_v if cls_v != default_v else _sentinel for cls_v, default_v in zip(cls._ID, ID())]
            super_id = next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda scls: "_ID" not in scls.__dict__, cls.__mro__[1:]))._ID
            final_fields = [cls_v if cls_v is not _sentinel else super_v for cls_v, super_v in zip(new_fields, super_id)]
            cls._ID = ID(*final_fields)
```

And after pasting this in a REPL we have:

```
In [31]: class B(A):
    ...:     _ID = ID(second="blip")
    ...: 

In [32]: B._ID
Out[32]: myTuple(first='default from parentclass', second='blip', third=None, fourth=None)

In [33]: class C(B):
    ...:     _ID = ID(fourth="blop")
    ...: 

In [34]: C._ID
Out[34]: myTuple(first='default from parentclass', second='blip', third=None, fourth='blop')
```